# How to search for the All the numbers after special character "|" using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, substring

Basically I have few records that in field that has special character usually like following:

```
id      Content
1         1|1232
2         23|12323
3         33|233223
```

I would like to write a query that select the numbers on the right side of the pipe "|"

so the result should be as follows:
result for query

```
1   =   1232
2   =   12323
```

ext...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple string functions:

```sql
SELECT id,
       SUBSTR( content, 1, INSTR( content, '|' ) - 1 ) AS before_pipe,
       SUBSTR( content, INSTR( content, '|' ) + 1 ) AS after_pipe
FROM   table_name
```

Or, using regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT id,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( content, '^\d+' ) AS before_pipe,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( content, '\d+$' ) AS after_pipe
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, content ) AS
SELECT 1, '1|1232' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '23|12323' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '33|233223' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | ID | BEFORE_PIPE | AFTER_PIPE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 1232 |
> | 2 | 23 | 12323 |
> | 3 | 33 | 233223 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fec524f165e829451aa303ed6e0bce9b)*

Answer (score 1):

Based on sample data, see if any of these two options (substr + instr and regular expressions) help. Sample data in lines #1 - 5, query begins at line#6.

```
SQL> with test (id, content) as
  2    (select 1, '1|1232'    from dual union all
  3     select 2, '23|12323'  from dual union all
  4     select 3, '33|233223' from dual
  5    )
  6  select id,
  7    content,
  8    --
  9    substr(content, instr(content, '|') + 1) result_1,
 10    regexp_substr(content, '\d+$') result_2
 11  from test;

        ID CONTENT   RESULT_1        RESULT_2
---------- --------- --------------- ---------------
         1 1|1232    1232            1232
         2 23|12323  12323           12323
         3 33|233223 233223          233223

SQL>
```